# Drupal, how to expose specific node data without authentication via RESTful Web Services

Tags: php, rest, drupal, drupal-7

I have installed [RESTful Web Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws) for my drupal application.

Now I can access to my data via these links

```
example.com/nodes/<id_of_node>.json
```

I can get All nodes by type

```
example.com/nodes.json?type=mytype
```

However, these links are working **only when I have logged in as Admin**. How to make these datas with **specific types** able to get via RESTfull API without any authentication?

I don't want any authentication, because the data that I want to show are public and does not provide sensible private information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RESTful Web Services defines a series of access permissions for the resources it is exposing. You need to make sure the anonymous role is able to access the resources you would like shared publicly. Drupal permissions are set at: `/admin/people/permissions`

For none programming questions about Drupal you may also want to try [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: My unauthorized people can see published materials. However, it is available only via this kind of link `example.com/some-kind-of-slug-text`. I can't find permission which allows me to access it via `example.com/nodes/<id_of_node>.json` like links.

Comment: The permission names are in the form: Access the resource [resource name]. Are you not seeing anything like that on the permissions list?

Comment: Yes I was able to find them. Thank you